# Java API to connect to any kind of database(oracle, mysql, mssql, db2, h2 etc...)

Tags: java, database, database-connection

I have a typical requirement from my client. There will be several types of databases that I need to connect to and collect some data from them and invoke a webservice with collected data. He will provide all datasource configurations to connect to respected database. based on datasource I need to figure out which database it is and need to prepare a connection management to connect to respected database.

Before hand, I would like to know, Is there any off the shelf API that could suite my requirement. I googled but no luck and hence landed here to post query. Suggestions are invited.

Comment: Perhaps [DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductName--)

Answer (score 0):

With [Java Database Connectivity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) (JDBC) you can connect to any of the above databases, and there are open source drivers for those and many more.

Here's [an example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) of using JDBC with MySQL. You use the same method to connect to any datasource with a given JDBC driver.